# Fetch Live Data from API and show notification

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I am a front end developer and good in react but want someone to guide/help me in this.

The backend is ready and it uses token as authentication with every API call.

I can easily call the API using setInterval for 2 3 seconds to fetch notifications data but I want to learn how to fetch live data from API.

I looked into socket.io tutorials and everyone is making chat app using Nodejs, so I don't how to use socket.io for real time data. I maybe wrong here.

I looked into meteor also but my project is already 80% developed and I can't rework to covert it into meteor react and I don't even know whether meteor is perfect for this scenario.

I have done my research and finally gave up and now asking here who has knowledge of this. Thank you.

Comment: What stack does back end use? Do you need two way real time or just server sent data and client receives only?

Comment: The backend is developed using Flask. When i call the notification using my token then server will send the response data.

Comment: Not a flask developer and you probably want to tag this appropriately to include it but I  imagine it also has web sockets libraries. If all you need on client side is to receieve look into *Server Sent Events* API

Comment: If you don't want to poll, you will have to use web sockets. Here's something which might help you. https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @charlietfl is right. I wasn't aware of Server Sent Events API. If all you need is to fetch data and show some notifications, you can use Server Sent Events API (because it is uni-directional - only from server to client).
You can google "Server Sent Events in flask" and find many resources specifically for Flask and React.